# How do I put a box between sliverAppBar and sliverToBoxAdapter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I developed mobile app with Flutter. I'm trying to code the following design;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NppaS.jpg)

I'm trying code. But I couldn't make the box in the middle of the page that says the title of the news.

The codes I wrote are as follows:

```
class PostDetailPage extends StatefulWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  final PostModel postDetail;
  const PostDetailPage({super.key, required this.postDetail});

  @override
  State<PostDetailPage> createState() => _PostDetailPageState();
  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);
}

late bool isDarkMode;
double top = 0.0;

class _PostDetailPageState extends State<PostDetailPage> {
  List<Widget> parsedWidgets = [];

  final double _expandedHeight = 250;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    var themeProvider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context, listen: false);
    isDarkMode = themeProvider.isDark;
    loadHtmlData();
  }

  loadHtmlData() {
    final document = parser.parse(widget.postDetail.content);
    final List<dom.Node> nodes = document.body!.nodes;
    // ...    
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var postDetail = widget.postDetail;
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          sliverAppBar(postDetail),
          sliverToBoxAdapter(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  SliverToBoxAdapter sliverToBoxAdapter() {
    return SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: isDarkMode
              ? ColorConstants.darkBlack4
              : ColorConstants.lightWhite,
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
            topRight: Radius.circular(20),
          ),
        ),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: parsedWidgets),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  SliverAppBar sliverAppBar(PostModel postDetail) {
    return SliverAppBar(
      pinned: true,
      snap: false,
      floating: false,
      expandedHeight: _expandedHeight,
      toolbarHeight: 55,
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      leading: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: IconButtonWidget(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_left_outlined),
          iconColor: ColorConstants.darkBlack2,
          iconSize: 30,
          backgroundColor: ColorConstants.darkYellow,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          onTap: () {
            Get.back();
          },
        ),
      ),
      flexibleSpace: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) {
          top = constraints.biggest.height;
          print(top);
          return FlexibleSpaceBar(
            stretchModes: const [
              StretchMode.fadeTitle,
            ],
            background: Image.network(
              postDetail.imageUrl,
              width: double.infinity,
              height: _expandedHeight,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
      actions: [
        Row(
          children: [
            IconButtonWidget(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.more_horiz),
              iconColor: ColorConstants.darkBlack2,
              backgroundColor: ColorConstants.darkYellow,
              ratio: 40,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              onTap: () {
                // Bottom sheet
              },
            ),
            const SizedBox(width: 10),
            IconButtonWidget(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.open_in_new),
              iconColor: ColorConstants.darkBlack2,
              backgroundColor: ColorConstants.darkYellow,
              ratio: 40,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              onTap: () {
                // webde oku
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        const SizedBox(width: 10),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I need for help. I did research but couldn't find a solution. My English is bad, Sorry...

Comment: Hi, you can try this package https://pub.dev/packages/sliver_fab

Comment: @Genius_balu Hi. Sorry, I can't use the package.

Answer (score 0):

Another `SliverToBoxAdaptor`

```
 sliverAppBar(postDetail),
 SliverToBoxAdapter(
    child: SizedBox(
        height: 250,
    ),
),
sliverToBoxAdapter(),
```

Explanation

[CustomScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html)

> A CustomScrollView lets you supply `slivers` directly to create various scrolling effects, such as lists, grids, and expanding headers.

[Slivers](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView/slivers.html)

> sliver (noun): a small, thin piece of something.

> A sliver is a widget backed by a RenderSliver subclass, i.e. one that implements the constraint/geometry protocol that uses SliverConstraints and SliverGeometry.

Comment: Hello. I already wrote the code you wrote. What I want is the box I want to open `sliverAppBar` and I want it above `sliverToBoxAdapter`. as in the picture.